# Azure Datafactory LinkedService gives the wrong type and type properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I created a LinkedService of the type **"Web"**. When I test it locally with the help of https://github.com/gbrueckl/Azure.DataFactory.LocalEnvironment I got the LinkedService's type as `Web` and the TypeProperties as `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Models.WebLinkedService`.

But when I test it in Azure I got the type as `WebLinkedService` and the TypeProperties as `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Models.GenericLinkedService`

I have the same problem with a LinkedService of the type **"AwsAccessKey"**. Azure.DataFactory.LocalEnvironment gives me the type as `AwsAccessKey` and the TypeProperties as `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Models.AwsAccessKeyLinkedService`

But again in Azure I get a different type, namely `CustomDataSource` instead of `AwsAccessKey` and the Typeproperties as `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Models.CustomDataSourceLinkedService`

Which types are correct? It feels like Azure.DataFactory.LocalEnvironment gives the correct ones and Azure not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I decided to adapt my code that parses this linked service as:

```
                var svcRTP = svcRTPServices as CustomDataSourceLinkedService;

                if (svcRTP != null)
                {
                    // ... your code ... 
                }
                else
                {
                    var svcRTPServ = svcRTPServices as WebLinkedService;
                    // ... your code ...
                }
```